# CentOS 7 yum basic authentication

Tags: linux, yum

For whatever reason, yum for CentOS 7 isn't using Basic Authentication to authenticate with the http proxy when using the proxy_username and proxy_password lines in yum.conf. CentOS 6 used to use Basic but CentOS 7 is trying ntlm (which is supposed to fail). Is there a way to force basic?

Comment: Why the heck would this be downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/yum.conf set
`proxy=http://<usernane>:<password>@proxy-url:port`

for me it helps with ntlm auth